# PyQt4 storing variable

Tags: variables, input, pyqt4

I started creating my first GUI with PyQt4 a few hours ago and I've caught a snag. I've researched all over the web and while some resources have come close they've never really answered my question.

Basically I want to know if it is possible to take user input text from a widget and store that text into a variable from a button click.

So far I have looked into QLineEdit methods but have not found what I am looking for. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
...
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)
        ...

    def on_button_click(self):
        self.variable = self.line_edit.text()
        print(self.variable)
...
```

Comment: This is definitely a start! but now when I set a variable to the function I get a none value when I try to concatenate it to a string.

variable = on_button_click()
print('this shows a ' + str(variable) + ' value')

shows up as this shows a None value

Comment: @ZacForester You shouldn't call the function, it will be called automatically when the button is clicked, if you connect it beforehand. I've edited the answer, maybe it will be clearer now.

Comment: @ZacForester: This is the answer to the question. Beyond this, I think you might be facing some fundamental issues. It might require you following a book to learn how python and pyqt work together.